# Have you ever experienced connection issues with Postgres database' based on just a db name?

Tags: postgresql

I've been idly bashing away at an issue with Postgres for months now. I've a bit of software (custom in-house stuff) that on 24 out of 25 servers does a certain process absolutely fine, no issues what so ever.

On the 25th server though, the process wouldn't quite complete properly, it would fail at the final hurdle which was a simple date change.

It's been a back-burner type issue so I'd not committed much time to working it out until management started to get angsty so I spent most of yesterday bashing away at it.

Obvious checks were done first:

- Postgres version (9.6)
- Software version
- Windows patches (Server 2019)
- GPO's
- NTFS permissions
- etc

All checked out as matches across every server. Went through the Postgres and the in-house software logs at length, had one of the developers build a stand alone executable for the process with a ridiculous amount of logging, still no dice. No indicators. Procmon and Wireshark logs showed the same story, nothing clear at all as to what was going on.

So then we take a backup of the database, load it in with a different name for testing and start running the process to find that it now works fine on the cloned database. This leads us to thinking there's maybe a formatting issue of some kind in the database, conscious of the idea that doing the backup & restore would shake things around. So we go back to the live, back it up again - delete the DB from postgres and restore from the backup.

No dice. Still broken.

Cue some serious confusion. We've done essentially the same thing with cloning live to test and are still getting the same fault at the end of the process.

After some head scratching and more prodding around in the logs I hit upon an idea of doing a fresh backup of the live DB, deleting the database, restoring the backup with a different name and then pointing the live software install to the newly named live DB and testing the process again.

It works!

For clarity, the filenames are basic alpha only. Upper case and lower case. No numbers, no symbols. Less than 15 characters in length.

I'm at a loss as to why it's now working and I'd love to get some input from the community.

Comment: As this is not a simple "here is a problem/error, do you have a solution" type of question that requires a lot of back and forth and investigation, I don't think it fits Stackoverflow. The Postgres (admin) mailing list is probably a better place to ask this.

Comment: You managed to tell a long story while carefully avoiding most relevant details. Amazing. All we know is that you are running PostgreSQL 9.6 on Windows. You should tell us: 1) how exactly you installed and configured PostgreSQL 2) with what software you are trying to connect to it, and how that software is configured 3) the exact error messages you got 4) what exactly those Wireshark and Procmon protocols show in the case of the problem. Adding relevant tags will help.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - I take your point.

1: Postgres installed with it's own installer. Totally default settings at installation.
2: The in-house software is just that, and meaningless to anyone else. It is built with .Net/Native Assembly.
3: None, there-in lies the rub. It simply wouldn't change the date at the end of the process.
4: Nothing unusual, comms to postgres was fine, and it could do every other step of the process (which is both reads and writes).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - a thoroughly reasonable point of view. I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: Oh! Your query title led me to believe that you have connection problems. Now it seems that you can connect - or did you just forget to check error return codes? If you don't post the relevant C# code or the details of your configuration, how should anyone without a magic crystal ball divine where exactly the problem is? You are obviously hoping that someone will come up and say "ah, yes, I had exactly the same thing, and it was X". But that is unlikely, and with the vagueness of your description, it could be all kinds of things that went wrong, so odds are that the guess is wrong.

Comment: To enumerate some possible causes: 1) you didn't check error return codes, and your transaction was rolled back 2) you connected to a different database by mistake 3) a code error made you forget to commit before you closed the connection. And that's just the first few things that come to my mind. This cannot be solved with Q&A, you'd need a consultant who looks at your system and holds your hand.

Comment: The database name is not a file name, it just an identifier in the system catalogs. So when you are referring to file names are you talking about something else?  Also what is the actual code that failed to execute?